# Regex Currency formatting in c# (Xamarin)

Tags: regex, xamarin, xamarin.forms, currency-formatting

While entering a Currency value in the Text Field, with help of Regex how do I, automatically make the Comma's to appear while the user is entering the values in a Numeric Text Field.

Eg:

$1

$15

$153

$1,530

$15,306

$1,53,068

Comma's should automatically be replaced as i keep inserting digits.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's `$1,53,068` exactly?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin a typo I suppose

Comment: its a currency field on my iOS Device.

Comment: Another way is Count the `string.length()` while user is entering the text and inset `,` according to string length, like checking if string length is 5 then use `string.insert()` to insert that at particular index! but this is only useful when you know that how many maximum characters are going to be there in your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two-step replacement procedure:

1. Get rid of all commas inserted so far by replacing

   ```
   ,
   ```

   by an empty string.
2. Insert new commas at all positions where the number of digits to the right is divisible by three and the character to the left is not `$`:

   ```
   (?<!\$)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)
   ```

   simply apply the pattern to the numbers without commas, and replace the pattern by `,`.

   Here is the [Demo of the second stage](https://regex101.com/r/Z5ziHY/1):

   Input:

   ```
   $1
   $15
   $153
   $1530
   $15306
   $153068
   $1530683456543456
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   $1
   $15
   $153
   $1,530
   $15,306
   $153,068
   $1,530,683,456,543,456
   ```

**Edit:** The demo is PCRE, but I tried not to use any features not available in C#. It seems to work [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%24%29%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b3%7d%29%2b%24%29&i=%241%0d%0a%2415%0d%0a%24153%0d%0a%241530%0d%0a%2415306%0d%0a%24153068&r=%2c&o=m) too.